# Some code in shortcode function being ignored

Tags: plugins, php, shortcode

I have the following code that's part of the shortcodes for a plugin, and I've been trying to debug why it seems to skip a call to `do_shortcode`. To debug I've been trying to have it write to a log file (just temporarily editing the code in the plugin to try various logging methods). But the weird thing is that only the last `file_put_contents()` call actually does anything. The rest just seem to be skipped, like they're not even there.

I've even tried putting together one long string at each debug point and then writing it in the `file_put_contents()` call that seems to work... except then it seems *none* of them work. I don't know what else to try. It's driving me insane. (Please note: I didn't originally write this plugin, I'm just trying to discover why it's stopped working since we upgraded to Wordpress 4.4. I also can't upgrade the plugin or the theme that it comes from because the site's theme was built on top of the theme, instead of as a child theme, and it's a spaghetti tangle that could so easily fall in a heap should I tug on the wrong strand.)

```
add_shortcode('tabs', 'kopa_shortcode_tabs');

function kopa_shortcode_tabs($atts, $content = null) {

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(), $atts));
    $log_string = "";
    $i = 0;
    //CUSTOM DEBUG CODE START
    $log_string += "Dealing with " . count($atts) . " tab(s)\n";
    file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wp_log/test_log", "Test " . $i++ . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
    //CUSTOM DEBUG CODE END

    $out = '';

    //CUSTOM DEBUG CODE START
    $log_string += "Handling content: " . $content . "\n";
    file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wp_log/test_log", "Test " . $i++ . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
    //CUSTOM DEBUG CODE END

    $out .= '<div class="list-container-1">';

    $out .= '<ul class="tabs-1 clearfix">';

    foreach ($atts as $key => $tab) {

        $out .= '<li><a href="#' . $key . '">' . $tab . '</a></li>';
        //CUSTOM DEBUG CODE START
        $log_string += "Added key = " . $key . "; tab = " . $tab . "\n";
        file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wp_log/test_log", "Test " . $i++ . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
        //CUSTOM DEBUG CODE END
    }

    $out .= '</ul>';

    $out .= '</div>';

    $out .= '<div class="tab-container-1">';

    $out .= do_shortcode($content);

    $out .= '</div>';
    //CUSTOM DEBUG CODE START
    $log_string += "Result: " . $out . "\n";
    //file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wp_log/test_log", $log_string . "Run Complete\n", FILE_APPEND);
    file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wp_log/test_log", "Test " . $i++ . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
    error_log($log_string . "Run Complete\n\n\n");
    //CUSTOM DEBUG CODE END
    return $out;

}
```

Comment: Before we go any further, do you have [debugging enabled](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic yes, debugging is enabled, and whether I set it to display or write to a file I don't get any output from it.

Answer (score 0):

This line is your issue:

```
$log_string += "Dealing with " . count($atts) . " tab(s)\n";
```

It should be:

```
$log_string .= "Dealing with " . count($atts) . " tab(s)\n";
```

It looks like you confused the javascript and PHP concatenation operator. Don't worry, it's something I've done numerous times!  Ugh!

Edit: Actually, looks like you've made this mistake on other lines as well.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't the problem. An earlier version of this (I think that's about the twelfth iteration I've posted up there) had `.=` as its in-place concatenation operator, and it didn't work any better. The use of `+` instead of `.` is mostly a sign of desperation as I was running out of ideas.